# System freezes under load. Which component should I replace?

Tags: debian, freeze

My system randomly freezes under heavy load with no diagnosable information found in system logs. I am running Debian stable on the machine.

My machine is about 4 years old with AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor, 8 GiB of RAM, NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210], 5 hard disks (500, 160, 160, 120, 40 GB). The CPU is about 80 degrees under heavy load.

What should I do to determine which component is faulty?

Edit: I may have mistaken the temperature. System monitor shows that CPUTIN is about 82 degrees and k10temp is about 63 degrees on full load. Is it too hot?

Comment: Clean out all the dust.  At 80 degrees C that AMD processor is overheating.

Comment: @MarkUbben has the correct answer below, the temperature of the CPU is most likely to high and the system is freezing or locking up. Clean out the fan and heatsink and if the normal temps don't stay below 55C then I would remove the heatsink and fan, clean the CPU and heatsink and apply quality thermal paste. If temps are still too high, I would get a good, quality heatsink/fan assembly and replace the stock one. We have had several AMD FX-8 series CPU's that the stock cooler just isn't enough, a $20 investment will go a long way.

Comment: I would still state that it's getting too hot.  Even 63 is higher than the recommended 61. It's a low cost fix, and would explain why you have no logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

80C is too high

Sounds like the fan needs to be replaced, or new thermal paste used.

All the specs I found show 61C is the max temp.

http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-8120.html